# unable to extent a list from multiple lists

Tags: python

i have a dictionary called "drs_groups" that it value are lists ,each list
contains Sevres server names
i am trying to create anew list called drs_list and append all the lists
to it like below

```
drs_list = []
for drs_role,esxs in drs_groups.iteritems():
    drs_list.extend(esxs)
```

if i iterate over the dictionary values i will get a list of servers:

```
['server1.com', 'server2.com', 'server3']
['server4.com', 'server5.com', 'server6']
```

if i will print drs_list i am not getting one list with all the lists
items inside ,what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: drs_groups.values()

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict.**[values](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_values.htm)**() method to get a list from a dictionary.

```
drs_groups.values()
```

**EX:**

```
import itertools
d = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]}
print list(itertools.chain(*d.values()))
```

**Result:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```